# Paypal Payment method?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a paypal payment method to finish my app using it as a project for University and i can't find a solution i am so confused. 
I added to build.gradle

```
//Paypal
implementation 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.15.3'
```

Also here is the logcat: https://ibb.co/hkJeZw

And here is my code in cart:

```
package com.example.onix.AndroEat;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.onix.AndroEat.Common.Common;
import com.example.onix.AndroEat.Database.Database;
import com.example.onix.AndroEat.Model.MyResponse;
import com.example.onix.AndroEat.Model.Notification;
import com.example.onix.AndroEat.Model.Order;
import com.example.onix.AndroEat.Model.Request;
import com.example.onix.AndroEat.Model.Sender;
import com.example.onix.AndroEat.Model.Token;
import com.example.onix.AndroEat.Remote.APIService;
import com.example.onix.AndroEat.ViewHolder.CartAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalConfiguration;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalPayment;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentConfirmation;
import com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import com.example.onix.AndroEat.Common.Config;

import info.hoang8f.widget.FButton;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyConfig;
import uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyContextWrapper;

public class Cart extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE = 9999;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference requests;

    public TextView txtTotalPrice;
    FButton btnPlace;

    List<Order> cart = new ArrayList<>();

    CartAdapter adapter;

    APIService mService;

    //Paypal payment
    static PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration()
            .environment(PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX) // use Sandbox because we test
            .clientId(Config.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID);
    String address,comment; //


    //Press Ctrl+O


    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Note : add this code before setContentView method
        CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/restaurant_font.otf")
        .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
        .build());

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);

        //Init paypal
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PayPalService.class);
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION,config);
        startService(intent);

        //Init Service
        mService = Common.getFCMService();

        //Firebase
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        requests = database.getReference("Requests");

        //Init
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.listCart);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        txtTotalPrice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total);
        btnPlace = (FButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlaceOrder);

        btnPlace.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (cart.size() > 0)
                    showAlertDialog();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(Cart.this, "Your cart is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        loadListFood();


    }

    private void showAlertDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Cart.this);
        alertDialog.setTitle("One more step!");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Enter your address:");


        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        View order_address_comment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.order_address_comment, null);

        final MaterialEditText edtAddress = (MaterialEditText) order_address_comment.findViewById(R.id.edtAddress);
        final MaterialEditText edtComment = (MaterialEditText) order_address_comment.findViewById(R.id.edtComment);

        alertDialog.setView(order_address_comment);
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp);

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                //Show Paypal to payment

                //first , get Address and Comment from Alert Dialog
                address = edtAddress.getText().toString();
                comment = edtComment.getText().toString();

                String formatAmount = txtTotalPrice.getText().toString()
                                        .replace("£","")
                                        .replace(",","");


                PayPalPayment payPalPayment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(formatAmount),
                        "GBP",
                        "AndroEat app Order",
                        PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PaymentActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION,config);
                intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT,payPalPayment);
                startActivityForResult(intent,PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE);

            }
        });

        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();
    }

    //Press Ctrl+O

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE)
        {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                PaymentConfirmation confirmation = data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
                if(confirmation != null)
                {
                    try{
                        String paymentDetail = confirmation.toJSONObject().toString(4);
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(paymentDetail);



                //Create new Request
                Request request = new Request(
                        Common.currentUser.getPhone(),
                        Common.currentUser.getName(),
                       address,
                        txtTotalPrice.getText().toString(),
                        "0", // status
                        comment,
                        jsonObject.getJSONObject("response").getString("state"), // State from JSON
                        cart
                );

                //Submit to Firebase
                //We will using System.CurrentMilli to key
                String order_number = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
                requests.child(order_number)
                        .setValue(request);
                //Delete cart
                new Database(getBaseContext()).cleanCart();

                sendNotificationOrder(order_number);

                Toast.makeText(Cart.this, "Order Placed, Thank you.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)
                Toast.makeText(this, "Payment cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else if(resultCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID)
                Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid payment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void sendNotificationOrder(final String order_number) {
        DatabaseReference tokens = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Tokens");
        Query data = tokens.orderByChild("isServerToken").equalTo(true); // get all node with isServertoken is true
        data.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Token serverToken = null;
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                   serverToken = postSnapShot.getValue(Token.class);
                }

                    //Create raw payload to send
                    Notification notification = new Notification("EDMT Dev", "You have new order " + order_number);
                    Sender content = new Sender(serverToken.getToken(), notification);


                    mService.sendNotification(content)
                            .enqueue(new Callback<MyResponse>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(Call<MyResponse> call, Response<MyResponse> response) {

                                    //Only run when get result
                                    if(response.code() == 200) {
                                        if (response.body().success == 1) {
                                            Toast.makeText(Cart.this, "Thank you , Order Place", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            finish();
                                        } else {
                                            Toast.makeText(Cart.this, "Failed !!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                        }
                                    }

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(Call<MyResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                                    Log.e("ERROR", t.getMessage());
                                }
                            });

                }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


    }

    private void loadListFood() {
        cart = new Database(this).getCarts();
        adapter = new CartAdapter(cart, this);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        //Calculate total price
        int total = 0;
        for (Order order : cart)
            total += (Integer.parseInt(order.getPrice()))*(Integer.parseInt(order.getQuantity()));
        Locale locale = new Locale("en", "UK");
        NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);

        txtTotalPrice.setText(fmt.format(total));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getTitle().equals(Common.DELETE))
            deleteCart(item.getOrder());
        return true;
    }

    private void deleteCart(int position) {
        //We will remove item at List<Order> by position
        cart.remove(position);
        //After that , we will delete all old data from SQLite
        new Database(this).cleanCart();
        //And final , we will update new data from List<Order> to SQLite
        for (Order item : cart)
            new Database(this).addToCart(item);
        //Refresh
        loadListFood();
    }
}
```

And my Request code:

```
package com.example.onix.AndroEat.Model;

import java.util.List;


public class Request {
    //Add new field state payment
    private String phone;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String total;
    private String status;
    private String comment;
    private String paymentState;
    private List<Order> foods; // list of food order

    public Request() {
    }

    public Request(String phone, String name, String address, String total, String status, String comment, String paymentState, List<Order> foods) {
        this.phone = phone;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.total = total;
        this.status = status;
        this.comment = comment;
        this.paymentState = paymentState;
        this.foods = foods;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(String total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    public String getPaymentState() {
        return paymentState;
    }

    public void setPaymentState(String paymentState) {
        this.paymentState = paymentState;
    }

    public List<Order> getFoods() {
        return foods;
    }

    public void setFoods(List<Order> foods) {
        this.foods = foods;
    }
}
```

Also i have a java class names 'Config1 where inside is the `public static final String PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID =`  where i get if from Sandbox add app on paypal.

Comment: Actually is working when i put custom value on BigDecimal for example:  PayPalPayment payPalPayment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal("10"), BUT is not working for total ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse your `formatAmount` string value to int and pass it in `BigDecimal`, in this below code:

```
PayPalPayment payPalPayment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(formatAmount),
                    "GBP",
                    "AndroEat app Order",
                    PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);
```

Comment: Um, sorry but i didn't understand how t do this :$ like this? PayPalPayment payPalPayment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(Integer.parseInt(formatAmount)),

Sorry for misunderstanding :(

Comment: Yes, you can do like this. But, before parsing `string` to `integer`, make sure that the input is a `number` not a `characters`.
You can do this by making your `editText` `inputType` to `number` or by `if check`

Comment: Still nothing Sir :(

Comment: Add a debug point in code on below line:
`String formatAmount = txtTotalPrice.getText().toString()
                        .replace("£","")
                        .replace(",","");`
Check there that what is the value of `formatAmount` is it a `number` or `string`.
As because the exception your getting is `NumberFormatException`, which means you are passing a `string` where `int` is required.

Comment: um.. am not sure Sir.. like that??? Sorry :( am too tired haven't sleep 43 hours trying to finish this app.
String formatAmount = txtTotalPrice.getText().toString()
                                        .replace("£","")
                                        .replace(",","");
PayPalPayment payPalPayment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(Integer.parseInt(formatAmount)),

Comment: I need to delete "¤" before 3300 to convert to number but i don't have  "¤" on my code :$

Comment: Check in `editText` in your `xml-layout` of this screen, might be you have input this character by mistake.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Am at work will check when i go home and let you know. thank you Sir

Comment: String formatAmount = txtTotalPrice.getText().toString()
                                        .replace("£","")
                                        .replace(",","");
This how is my code above PayPalPayment.

Comment: Nop i dont have it in my xml-layout

Comment: I just wondered where you got that nice class `PayPalPayment` that supports `BigDecimal` and found out its the Android SDK. The java SDK uses strings for enums and numbers. How unprofessional is their SDK and so its just an error prone auto-generated wrapper around their rest-service.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the locale "country" from "UK" to "GB" and works.
Thanks all for the help